How to remove a role from a user using the ID & check if they have a certain role using the ID discord.js v14
I have searched EVERYWHERE, and cannot find the answer.
So basically I'm making a role give & role remove command. I want to check if they already have the role, so I can stop the code. But it seems that everything I put after .roles just stops working. For example, I've tried .has,.remove, .cache, and .Contains, none of those worked. Does anyone have a solution?
I'm a beginner at coding so I apologize if anything is just flat-out stupid.

module.exports = {
    name: 'roleremove',
    description: 'Removes a specified role from a user.',
    // devOnly: Boolean,
    // testOnly: Boolean,
        // deleted: true,
    options: [
        {
            name: 'user',
            description: 'The user to remove the role from.',
            required: true,
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
        },
        {
            name: 'role',
            description: 'The role you want to remove',
            required: true,
            type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Role,
        }
    ],

    callback: async (client, interaction) => {
        const targetUser = interaction.options.get('user').value;
        const targetRole = interaction.options.get('role').value;
        const alreadyHasRole = targetUser.roles.Contains(targetRole)
        if (!alreadyHasRole) {
          interaction.reply({ content: `❌ | Could not remove ${targetUser}'s role because they dont have that role.`, ephemeral: true });
        } else {
          await targetUser.roles.remove(targetRole);
          interaction.reply({ content: `✅ | Successfully removed ${targetUser}'s role.`, ephemeral: true});
        }
      }
    };```


Nevermind. All I had to do was change the variables for 'targetUser' and 'targetRole' to interaction.options.getMember('user') //(my option name) and interaction.options.getRole('role').
Then, just remove the alreadyHasRole variable and make the if statement say if (!targetUser.roles.cache.has(targetRole.id)) {.
After that, everything worked.
Heres my code if it helps:
        const targetRole = interaction.options.getRole('role');
        // const alreadyHasRole = targetUser.roles.Contains(targetRole)
        if (!targetUser.roles.cache.has(targetRole.id)) {
          interaction.reply({ content: `❌ | Could not remove ${targetUser}'s role because they dont have that role.`, ephemeral: true });
        } else {
          await targetUser.roles.remove(targetRole);
          interaction.reply({ content: `✅ | Successfully removed ${targetUser}'s role.`, ephemeral: true});
        }

